# how to display data in descending order without using ORDER BY CLAUSE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle9i

I am new in oracle and I have one question i.e.:
how to display data in descending order without using ORDER BY CLAUSE in Oracle.
whether it is in sql or pl/sql.

Comment: A natural question would be: why do you avoid using the order by clause?

Comment: Why? And display where - SQL*Plus, some client application...?

Comment: What is the motivation for this, why do you need it?

Comment: Bad news: You **cannot** order data in a select statement without using `order by` clause.

Comment: Would you like some dehydrated water to go with that?

Comment: That is **not** possible. The ***only*** (really: the _only_) way to _guarantee_ an order of a select statement is to use `ORDER BY`. There is **no** alternative.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to reliably retrieve sorted results without explicitly using ORDER BY... if you cannot use ORDER BY, you would need to organize the code in whichever programming language you're using to pull the data with which is ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid ORDER BY, use a hierarchical query with flat results, and ORDER SIBLINGS! (okay, this will be exactly the same).

You can also do it with:

```
SELECT * FROM ...
START WITH 1 = 1
CONNECT BY 0 = 1
ORDER SIBLINGS BY ...
```

Comment: I don't know whether to +1 or -1 this :)

Comment: @Jefrey Kemp: -1 because of bad practice, +1 for answer that exactly fits the question?

Comment: No. -1 because `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` is, arguably, still an `ORDER BY` clause... +1 for chutzpah :D

Answer (score -1):

to sort ename in ascending order without using order by clause:

```
select ename from emp
union
select ename from emp;
```

Comment: Please spend a few minutes to properly format/indent your answer. There is a **lot** of explanation how to use our markdown language, right there, at the edit window!